# Replace a string with some part of a text file

Tags: java, regex, file, replace

I want to find a numbered pattern in a file (which I did successfully), convert it to my desired number format by using another method in the class (which I also did successfully)...

My problem is that I want to replace the new number format with the previous number format (which I don't know how) and write it to a new file.

```
  String INPUT = "D:\\input.txt";
  String OUTPUT = "D:\\output.txt";
  String all = "";
  Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile("\"(\\d{14}.{2}\\d{4})\"");
  try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(INPUT), "UTF-8"))) {
        String CurrentLine;
        while ((CurrentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            Matcher matcher = regexp.matcher(CurrentLine);
              if (matcher.find()) {
                  String number1 = CurrentLine.substring(10,20);
                  String number2 = CurrentLine.substring(30,40);
                  number1 = convertor(number1);
                  number2 = convertor(number2);
              }
            all = all + sCurrentLine + "\r\n";  \\create output to use for BufferedWriter
        }
```

BTW the above code is (as it's obvious) just a part of my entire code.

Comment: It's not clear what convertor does...

Comment: suppose the number formats are like this: 23+3 the convertor method sums the numbers and returns 26+0. The input is 20 characters, convertor output is also 20 characters.

Answer (score 0):

To save your output just execute this at end of loop.

```
Files.write(Paths.get(OUTPUT), all.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

The `matcher` object returns even the position where the group `(\d{14}.{2}\d{4})` has matched. I suggest to double check this part of your code to help yourself.

Use `matcher.start(1)` to have the start index of the subsequence captured by the group during the previous match operation.

Comment: I know exactly where the strings are found in those lines (which have numbers). Does this matcher.start(1) help me replace the converted pattern?

Comment: It was just a suggestion... if you already know how to do so far so good

Comment: Thanks but how can I replace the converted number with the original number?

Comment: No, because I didn't understand what it would do. I just solved it on my own. I just simply replaced the "CurrentLine" with the numbers I wanted -using replaceAll- and then saved it to String "all". Then I wrote "all". done.